# Postgresql PQgetvalue: array return

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I've a table created like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_test
(
  id        bigserial    PRIMARY KEY,
  interest  int          ARRAY[2]
);
```

I got `PGresult* res` using `PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_test");`

Now, how can I get `int[]` from `PQgetvalue(res, 0, 1)`.
I don't want to depend on structs defined in `array.h` as they might change.

I could not find any API in Postgresql docs which can do things.
Please advise.

Regards,
Mayank

Comment: You've specified what return type you want; but please update the question to be explicit about what return *value* you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PQgetvalue() returns the string representation of the field value unless you specify a binary cursor. In either case (string or binary cursor) you'll need to supply the code to manipulate the result into the form you want.

You might find some ideas in the [PostgreSQL source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/).

- src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c
- src/include/utils/array.h.

And there's some code in contrib/intarray.

At http://doxygen.postgresql.org/, click "Files", then search for "array".

At the string level, which is what PQgetvalue() returns, it's probably easy to Google up some code that extracts integers from an comma-delimited string.

Comment: Looks like its not possible what I need :)

Comment: Oh, it's possible. There's just not an API for it. You can write a function in C that accepts a string, like "{1,2,3}", and returns (or populates) an array of int. It's not dead simple, because you'd have to accommodate (or give up on) multi-dimensional arrays and arrays of arbitrary size. But it's possible. I knocked together some code to turn "{1,2,3}" into an array of int, and it wasn't too hard. (I learned to hate strtol(), though.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Catcall. I meant its not possible to get `int*` in return. Converting {x,y} is a different thing. Well, I'll be doing that :)